# css transition for mobile menu bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to animate the mobile menu when i click the menu icon .

so what i did for the menu :

```
.overlay-menu {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    z-index : 1040;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0,0, 0.5);
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
  }

  .mobile-menu {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1050 ;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
 
  }
```

I'm showing the overlay when i open the menu . using js.
so i tried to add `transition` to the `mobile-menu` class but its not doing anything .

```
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
```

the mobile nav :

```
    <nav class="mobile-menu shadow-sm" id="mobile-menu">
           
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">test</a>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
            
        </nav>
```

I'm using bootstrap 4 . i added this menu below the main menu .

used media queries to hide in bigger devices.

Is there anything wrong im doing here?

I'm still learning any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you please also add the JS part you use to show the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing/hiding an element you could change the opacity from invisible (`opacity: 0`) to visible. This will also make sure that CSS transitions will be applied.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#mobile-menu').toggleClass('hidden');
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #eee;
}

.overlay-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1040;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.mobile-menu {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1050;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

button {
  z-index: 1051;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Show menu
</button>
<nav class="mobile-menu shadow-sm hidden" id="mobile-menu">

  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">test</a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</nav>
```